# Rails Devise Login Sometimes Does Not Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app configured with devise and it works most of the time. Signup seems to have no issues at all.

Sometimes when trying to login an existing user (the same test user I've successfully logged in many times) The page does not redirect.

When I check the logs I see it logging that the redirect was successful. And if I refresh the page then I'm logged in. I haven't been able to reliably recreate the issue but it seems more likely to happen when the server is restarted.

I updated the redirect code to this:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    current_user.sync_with_crm
    current_user.save
    return stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end
```

The `current_user.sync_with_crm` makes an api call to my CRM and then sets some associations that I need to save on the user model. I don't know how this could be the issue as it does work most of the time.

Not even sure how to trouble shoot this further.

ruby 2.5, rails 5.2.0, devise 4.4.3